# Expected declaration in extension AFError

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to coding, so help is appreciated. I'm getting the error, "expected declaration- in extension of AFError". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It looks right to me. What do I do?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to change the syntax from Swift 2 to Swift 3 the converter destroyed the code of your Alamofire Framework. Always use the correct Framework Versions and don't try to update the code yourself. Also when running the converter, always just run in on your own code. Not on the code of Frameworks.